# C# Как создать свой собственный XLSX Reader

Tags: c#, excel

Есть формат excel файлов .xlsx

К примеру, чтобы прочитать его в C# нужно скачивать дополнение типа EPPlus.

Возник вопрос, как самому к примеру можно написать такое дополнение именно к xlsx расширению ?

Я не пойму на чём базируются такие дополнения, ведь к примеру, если взять допустим голый Win, скачать на него файл .xlsx, а под рукой будет любая версия C# Studio.

Возможно ли в таких условиях написать "что" чтобы прочитать .xlsx файл ?

Надеюсь мысль вопроса была понятна

Comment: "Возможно ли в таких условиях написать "что" чтобы прочитать .xlsx-файл?" - а ничего не нужно "писать" для этого. .xlsx-файл - это zip-архив, и что бы вычитать зип-архив - нужен батник и всё. Вычитывайте файлики из архива и кладите их временно куда то. И дальше разбирайтесь как устроена структура данных экселя. Внутри сжатого .xlsx-файла - набор xml-файлов. Ну а эти xml-файлы расковыривайте например штатными xml-парсерами.

Comment: У майкрософта есть спецификации форматов офисных файлов. Прямо сейчас не найду ссылку, но своими глазами про ворд видел. Не скажу, что они богатые, но основное понимание будет.

Comment: Как это .zip архив ? Как мне тогда увидеть  xml в  .xlsx ?

Comment: Понял. Вопрос, тогда как работают те же расширения для C# VS ? EEPLUS к примеру, у них что там свои распаковщики и ридеры ? Я правильно понимаю ? Просто хотелось узнать подробней, как пишут такие вот дополнения на примере этого формата

Comment: "Как это .zip архив?" - ну вот так, зип-архив. Измените расширение ".xlsx" на ".zip". И откройте любым архиватором этот архив. Вы чего как маленький то? Откроете в архиваторе архив и увидите набор .xml-файликов - это и есть эксель-база-данных. Ну почти.

Comment: Смысл эксель-баз-данных - это собственно база-данных, и представление-базы-данных. Это разные "вещщи".

Comment: Открыл, всё отлично, понял как это. Только вопрос в другом. К примеру как работает то же дополнение EPPlus ? Я хочу узнать именно как эти все дополнения получают доступ к данным в файле, неужели они все распаковывают по вашему методу и парсят данные ? Нашел ещё вариант через - драйвер OLEDB, это уже ближе к истине, НО, пишут что он медленный, тогда всё таки что используют эти дополнения типа EEPlus ?

Comment: Вообще никаких проблем. оле! оле! оле! OLE! namespace Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel. Код для чтения нужен?

Comment: "неужели они все распаковывают по вашему методу и парсят данные?" - а как иначе? Но! Одно дело это база данных, а другое дело - это __статическая__ база данных. Если только "рид-онли" - то можно всё сильно ускорить. И представление бд - не нужно. Именно потому и пользуют собственные ридеры - статик-ридеры "по определению" только читают, да ещё и не вникают в подробности как это представлено. Потому работают сильно быстрее. Ридерам без представления данных - dom не нужен, даже xml-парсер не нужен, всё читается и парсится совершенно другими способами. Запредельно быстрыми способами.

Comment: OLE - это не мой сорт кофе. Олдфаги поймут.

Comment: Уточните что такое ридеры которым не нужен xml-парсер ? Вопрос изначально стоял в другом, на чём базируются все эти дополнения по чтению XLSX в Visual Studio - на распаковки в xml и считывании данных ? Получается они на этот метод делают что-то типа своего обработчика данных, с последующими методами которые описывают в фаге по применению их дополнения и всё ?... Т.е они на эту распаковку создают свою обвертку типа

Comment: 99.9% что так и есть. Ну не через псевдо-драйвер же это всё колупать? ЗАЧЕМ? Драйвер предназначен для динамических телодвижений, а для статических "рид-онли" - тем более каких то 10-100Кб юзать полный динамический стек - ну я даже не знаю, это премия Дарвина какая то.

Comment: "Уточните что такое ридеры которым не нужен xml-парсер?" - Это однопроходной парсер, который не строит dom-дерево, т.е. это не xml-парсер по-существу. Он последовательно "нагребает" данные и всё. Но структуру данных - не строит. Она не нужна.

Comment: Посмотрел в дополнения, которое "читает" xlsx - одна dll и один xml файл.  На счёт .zip конечно удивили, такой способ решает большинство проблем со считыванием.

Comment: И должен быть не зип, а рар :) Потому что рар - это космос по сравнению с зипом. Это шифрование, это отказоустойчивость, это самовосстановление, причём запредельно хорошо реализованное, и может быть даже единственно хорошо реализованное. Это хорошая реализация сжатия бд. А бд без отказоустойчивости - это не бд, а фикция. Плюс в раре есть вменяемая поддержка томов, а это уже инкрементальные бд - что есть запредельное тру, потому что возможна децентрализация итд итп. Собственно мои бд так и "живут" в рарах. Но опять же Майкрософт частично купил рар. Так что может быть рар будет и в экселе.

Comment: А ещё есть такой момент. Он не совсем касается "дополнений". Но этот момент касается того, что вам нужно. Рассмотрите следующий вариант. Всё это - это набор xml, однако же вы можете крутануть всё это через трансформации, и вывести как оно вам нужно, В БРАУЗЕРЕ. Вы изначально про голую вёнду+VS, но голая вёнда = вёнда+браузер. Т.е. можно глянуть на расширения эксплорера, и может быть они готовые есть. А если собственная реализация - то смотрите в сторону "xml/xslt", xslt - это гениальная штука, это подмножество xml, где xml - это данные, xslt - это представление данных, xslt гугол загубил.

Comment: Погуглил, примерно понял. Мне главное нужно было понять, как читать эти файлы (не прибегая к чьим-то сторонним расширениям) и узнать как это делают они, т.е на каком уровне типа.